# Helvetica Neue loads fine on Android

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap-3, fonts, webfonts, android-fonts

We designed our site using Bootstrap and hence used Helvetica Neue which is not pre-installed on Windows, hence the site did not look too good on Windows (because it fell back on Arial). Surprisingly, our site shows up fine on Android (i.e the Helvetica Neue font seems to be loaded since it appears exactly like it does on Mac).

We did multiple searches on the web and it seems Android phone should not have Helvetica Neue pre-installed.

Hence, we are puzzled why the site renders fine on Android (This question has become more important now since we have bought a web license for Helvetica Neue and we need to decide whether to load the license file for Android or not since we are paying per-view)

Comment: a comment with a downvote would be very helpful to know what's not good with the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some manufacturers include extra fonts in their skins. These fonts can sometimes be accessed. Please be aware that these fonts may not be available on all devices.

Comment: Thats good to know. We tested on multiple Android devices and all of them seemed to load Helvetica Neue. I wonder if most of the manufacturers out there end up including Helvetica Neue

Comment: Helvetica Neue is a font this loved by a lot of designers, so I wouldn't be surprised.